# Relationship between volume and area

Tags: nt.number-theory, dg.differential-geometry, cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry, differential-topology

Let $\mu(z) dV_n$ be a measure in $\mathbb{C} ^n$.
Let $B_n(r) := \{z \mid \|z\| < r\}$ be the ball of radius $r$ in $\mathbb C^n$, and $\partial B_n(r) $ be the corresponding sphere.
In $\mathbb{C} $ how can we find the following inequality?
$$
\operatorname{Vol}_{\mu}(B_1(r))=\int_{B_1(r)} \mu(z) dV_1(z)=
\int_0^r\left(\int_{\partial B_1(t)} \mu dz\right)dt\geq \int_0^r \left[\int_{\partial B_1(t)}(\mu)^{ \frac{1}{2}} \right]^2\frac{1}{2\pi t} dt
$$
And can we generalize this inequality in $\mathbb {C}^n$?

Comment: I tried to proofread this (for example, don't mix text and math in an equation; write $\operatorname{Vol}(B)$ `$\operatorname{Vol}(B)$`, not Vol$(B)$ `Vol$(B)$`), but I'm not sure I got everything right.  For example, you asked whether you could generate the inequality in $\mathbb C^n$, and I changed that to 'generalize'.  Please feel free to revert or re-edit if I got it wrong.

Comment: Please don't self-vandalize your own post. You can delete it if you like, as long as it has no answer (and also undelete it later).

Comment: You say "Let $\mu(z)dV$ is a measure on $\mathbb C^n$". So I guess $\mu$ is a function (namely, the density of your measure w.r.t Lebesgue). Q: What does it then mean to say "Let $B_\mu(r)$ be a ball in $\mathbb C^n$ ?". More precisely, $B_\mu(r)  = ???$

Comment: $Vol(B_\mu(r)) $ is the volume of the ball with respect to the measure $\mu dV$

Comment: $B(r) ={z\in\mathbb {C^n} ;|z|<r} $

Comment: This still doesn't make sense to me. What is subscripted set $B_{\mathbf{\mu}}(r) = ???$ which appears in your integrals ?

Comment: You can forget the index but if we measure it is with respect to $\mu$

Comment: OK, I've updated you question to more tightly reflect what you seem to intend.

Comment: See my post below for a complete solution to the general problem. It's based on the co-area formula + Jensen's inequality. The particular case of $\mathbb C$ (i.e $n=1$) is a consequence of the elementary fact that a circle of radius $t$ has length (i.e Hausdorff measure) equal to $2\pi t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be solved via co-area formula and Jensen's inequality. We will do it Bourbaki style, i.e from $n$-dimensional case  to particular case $n=1$.

---

Instead of $\mathbb C^n$, we can equivalently see the problem as a problem in $\mathbb R^m$, where $m=2n$ (i.e we isomorphically map real dimensions for each complex dimension). So, let $dV_m$ denote volume measure in $\mathbb R^m$ and $dS_{m-1}$ denote the corresponding surface area measure, i.e $(m-1)$-dimensional Hausdorff measure. The mapping $F: z \mapsto \|z\|$ on $\mathbb R^m$ has jacobian determinant $1$ (except at $z=0$, where it is undefined). Also note that for all $t \ge 0$, we have
$$
F^{-1}(\{t\})=\{z \in \mathbb R^m \mid F(z) = t\} = \{z \in \mathbb R^m \mid \|z\| = t\} = \partial B_m(t).
$$
By the coarea-formula (see [Corollary 1.4](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Elnicolae/Coarea.pdf), for example), we have
$$
\begin{split}
\int_{B_m(r)}\mu(z)dV_m(z) &= \int_{0}^r\left(\int_{F^{-1}(\{t\})}\frac{\mu(z)}{|Jac_F(z)|}dS_{m-1}(z)\right)dt\\
&= \int_{0}^r\left(\int_{\partial B_m(t)}\mu(z)dS_{n-1}(z)\right)dt\\
&= \int_{0}^r\left(\int_{\partial B_m(t)}\frac{\mu(z)}{S_{m-1}(\partial B_m(t))}dS_{m-1}(z)\right)S_{n-1}(\partial B_m(t))dt\\
&\ge\int_{0}^r\left(\int_{\partial B_m(t)}\frac{\mu(z)^{1/2}}{S_{m-1}(\partial B_m(t))}dS_{m-1}(z)\right)^2S_{m-1}(\partial B_m(t))dt\\
&= \int_{0}^r\left(\int_{\partial B_m(t)}\mu(z)^{1/2}dS_{m-1}(z)\right)^2\frac{1}{S_{m-1}(\partial B_m(t))}dt,
\end{split}
$$
where the inequality is an applicaiton of Jensen's inequality on the convex function $x \mapsto x^2$ and the probability measure $A \mapsto S_{m-1}(A \cap \partial B(t))/S_{m-1}(\partial B(t))$.

In particular, if $n=2$, we have $m=2\cdot 1 = 2$, $dS_{m-1} = dS_1$ which is the arc-length measure, and so $S_1(\partial B(t)) =$ length or circle of radius $t$, which equals $2\pi t$.

Comment: So there is no square!

Comment: The data in your question are still not clear. See my comments in the question above.

Comment: Ok, the situation is clearer now. My answer above solves both your particular (case $n=1$) and general problems (cases $n > 1$).

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Comment: OK, cool. If it anwsers your question, don't forgot to upvote and accept it. The is a button to the left for that :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109538/discussion-between-marouani-and-dohmatob).

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know how I can upvote and accept the answer

Comment: At the top left side of the the answer, click on the check mark to accept. There is also an up arrow (to upvote the answer), and a down arrow (to downvote).